# I am repeatedly zipping the same folder of files, but the shasum keeps changing

Tags: timestamps, zip, checksum

I am zipping a folder and fingerprinting it with its `shasum` however this keeps changing on every zipping. Same with `md5` any idea why? Is it working based on access time or something? Is there a way to keep it consistent? It used to be consistent when I was doing `git archive` into a zip, but now I am directly zipping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem with `tar` archives. There the differences were caused by atime and/or ctime entries. My solution was to use

```
tar -c --format=ustar ...
```

so that the timestamps were no longer part of the archive. Furthermore IIRC standard tar (i.e. GNU tar) creates a string describing the archive itself, and this string contains a timestamp. I.e. even if the archive content does not change at all the digest changes. This may be similar with ZIP.

For ZIP it seems that you can use the option `--no-extra` / `-X` to avoid file timestamps to be written to the archive. I just tested that. Without this option I get different archives but with the option they are the same.

Comment: Works! Spent hours on the man page.. not sure why i couldnt find it..

Comment: Hey do you know if this works with identical but newly created files? take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181099/repeatedly-ziping-a-file-that-is-newly-created-but-identical-however-the-shasu