# Repeatedly ziping a file that is newly created, but identical, however the shasum of the zip keeps changing

Tags: timestamps, zip, checksum

This is a followup to [I am repeatedly zipping the same folder of files, but the shasum keeps changing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166357/i-am-repeatedly-zipping-the-same-folder-of-files-but-the-shasum-keeps-changing) essentially..

I am trying to add a file containing the git sha of the current commit when I zip a part of my repository and take its sha sum..

The code for that is `git rev-parse HEAD > .gitsha`. However adding this to my zip means that the `shasum` of my zip keeps changing every second or so. The zip command uses `-X` to ignore file timestamps.

I experimented with just the `.gitsha` file below

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD > .gitsha ; shasum .gitsha
8fa263bc885822ccba03006ea10015ef32da485c  .gitsha
```

This is consistent over time.

However after ziping it, the `shasum` is no longer consistent

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD > .gitsha ; zip -X --quiet -r test.zip .gitsha ; shasum test.zip
26cc38c624f91a1c555d503fdfdecb1ce670274f  test.zip

$ git rev-parse HEAD > .gitsha ; zip -X --quiet -r test.zip .gitsha ; shasum test.zip
b03f7cb654e3aa0d25d18ead5fe1f225bc2aac9f  test.zip
```

These are 2 trials a few seconds apart. I presume that the `-X` flag does not include creation time perhaps? Any way to get this to work?

Update: Deleting the zip does not help.

```
$ rm test.zip; git rev-parse HEAD > .gitsha ; zip -X --quiet -r test.zip .gitsha ; shasum test.zip
76c722ccf2df75fb624f9640ad948f4508dd6152  test.zip
$ rm test.zip; git rev-parse HEAD > .gitsha ; zip -X --quiet -r test.zip .gitsha ; shasum test.zip
6bd26d2bc821d9f12806fc81a8ba8c8babcc664a  test.zip
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. The output of `git rev-parse <REV>` is SHA-1 hash of the specified revision, unique across all revisions of the repository. Why you would zip such a small string and then checksum the zipfile is a mystery.

Comment: @msw this zip is being distributed as a part of our product. This helps me debug if an issue is discovered with a particular zip. Does that make sense?

Comment: Have you tried comparing the zip listings of the two zip files? Have you tried a binary diff of them?

Comment: @pjc50 could you give me more details on what I should try? I presume the binary diff would be different cuz the shasum is.

Comment: what happens when you do the `-FS` switch with zip?

Comment: Diffoscope is an excellent modern tool to find precise differences between many formats, including ZIP files: https://diffoscope.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up generating a `.gitsha` for the repo in the root folder, and only rewriting it if it is out of date. This gives me what i want.. at the expense of exploding one line of code to 20..

```
new_sha=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
if [ -f ../.gitsha ]
then
   old_sha=$(cat ../.gitsha)
   if [ $old_sha = $new_sha ]
    then
    generate=false
    echo "gitsha file up to date"
   else
    generate=true
    echo "gitsha file out of date"
   fi
else
    echo "git sha file missing"
   generate=true
fi

if [ $generate = true ]
    then
    echo $new_sha > ../.gitsha
fi
```

instead of `git rev-parse HEAD > .gitsha`

Comment: Not quite a 1-1 answer, but this solved the root problem, so I am accepting this.

Answer (score 0):

The zip command appends to the output zip file.  Try deleting it between runs.

---

Update: I tested -X for myself and it seems that it still inserts the file timestamp in the file (as seen in `unzip -l`)

If you take a look at the [protocol on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#File_headers) you can see that the date and time fields are always present, and then at the end of the header they have room for OS-specific fields.  I would say that -X is leaving out those OS-specific extra fields.

So, I think the only way you can produce a consistent zip file is to have consistent timestamps.  You might try touching the file to a specific date before adding it to the zip file.

Comment: Perhaps I can generate the .gitsha on a post commit hook or something.. not pretty though..

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of the `strings` command on the zip files:

```
$ strings test.zip blah.zip                         
.gitshab9e1355d36643fefe94da0bee81533cd8cbb04d9
.gitshaPK
QH;F
.gitshab9e1355d36643fefe94da0bee81533cd8cbb04d9
QH;F
.gitshaPK
```

The content of the three strings remain the same, but the order changes. So there might be some component of the zip file which is not precisely order dependant. I'll update when I can determine how to make the output constant.

Comment: I repeated this, order was similar but the shasums were still different

Comment: @KarthikT perhaps it is *time* you looked into other approaches to identify your product.